# Bisectors problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I need help with this geometric problem. Given triangle ABC. CM is the bisector of $\angle ACB, M\in AB$ and $CN, N\in AB$ is the bisector of the suplementary angle of $\angle ACB$. B is between M and N. A circle with diameter MN is drawn. For any point P on the circle prove that:

$$\frac{PA}{PB}= \frac{AC}{BC}.$$

Comment: That looks false. PA/PB is fixed, but PM/PN is not.

Comment: Yet, no matter where is P on the circle that ratio remains fixed.

Comment: For $P$ close to $M$, the ratio $PM/PN$ is very small; for $P$ close to $N$, the ratio is very large.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I think the problem is wrong. They probably meant $\frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{AC}{BC}$

Comment: Just wondering, what is the supplementary angle of a given angle? I took a guess, but it does not always happen that B lies between M and N with my choice.

Comment: Take a point Q on the extension of the segment AC. Then $\angle BCQ$ is the suplementary of $\angle ACB$

Comment: That's what I guessed, chen h.; however consider a 45-45-90 triangle with legs AC, BC. Then the bisector of the supplementary angle of ACB is parallel to AB.

Comment: The problem states that the case we are looking at is not such.

Comment: So it is just a hypothesis that N exists and B lies between M and N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a two-focus definition of a circle as all points $X$ such that $\frac{XF_1}{XF_2}=k$ for a constant $k$, which can be applied here. First, since $CM$ is the internal bisector of $\angle ACB,$ we have $\frac{CA}{CB}=\frac{MA}{MB}.$

So if we *define* $k=\frac{MA}{MB}$ there is a circle $\frac{XA}{XB}=k$ using the two foci $A,B$ with $k$  as above, and this circle contains the point $C$ by choice.

Under your assumption the external bisector at $C$ happens to cross the (extended) side $AB$ of the given triangle at a point $N$ where $B$ is between $M$ and $N$.

We also have a right angle $MCN$ (using that the two angles are supplementary), making $MN$ the diameter of some circle going through point $C$, and in your assumptions this is the circle through $M,N$ you're considering. So that's the same as the above circle with general formula $$\frac{XA}{XB}=k,$$ which means we get $\frac{PA}{PB}=\frac{CA}{CB}$ for any point $P$ on the circle, by taking $P=X$ in that formula, and $k=\frac{MA}{MB}=\frac{CA}{CB}.$

*Edit:* To make this idea work we need a separate proof that the point $N$ also satisfies the circle equation $\frac{XA}{XB}=k.$ When this is brought down to length ratios it becomes (in one form) $\frac{CA}{NA}=\frac{CB}{NB},$ which one can show fairly easily using the law of sines. The need for this extra step is that we know we have a circle through $M,N$ containing the point $A,$ but in order to conclude this is the same as the circle $\frac{XA}{XB}=k$ we need both ends of the line segment to lie on that circle.